# What are ways of showing less data in dashboards?

Tags: dashboard, graphs, infographic

There are few selections in dashboard where data is very less i.e showing two bars in a graph which looks very odd. Is there any other way than graphs where we can display information in dashboards ?

*Here is the example I am referring to.*

**Case 1** - When there are multiple values for graph it looks good.
[image]

**Case 2** - When there is one value , one bar looks weird.
[image]

Comment: There are plenty of ways. Try looking at the D3 Library (https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery) or Google charts (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery). However, certain charts only work with certain kinds of data - without information about the kind of data you are trying to represent, the answers you get here will be too broad to be of use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading a very good book about data visualization recently, http://www.storytellingwithdata.com/
I came across with a very good suggestion. When you don't need a graph to represent something, don't use a graph. Just use the number itself. Don't try to give something that looks nice graphically, instead try to help the user understand better the information that you give.
In the case that you have, I would just use the 2 numbers as they are.

Comment: Also read any of Stephen Few's books on data visualisation, especially Information Dashboard Design (Stephen invented the Bullet Graph). If you are really interested in Data Visualisation, you would also read Edward Tufte, especially The Visual Display of Quantitative Information. Edward is the "father" of data visualisation, and he invented Sparklines.

Comment: @SteveD Thanks for the advice!! It is already on my list, but super expensive :(

Comment: Sadly a bit expensive - however the information contained in those books is well worth the investment, simply because Data Visualisation is such a huge subject and the knowledge is very much in demand right now - you cannot obtain this depth of knowledge on the cheap.if you buy just one book go for the second edition of Stephen Few's Information dashboard design book.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dimitra - I am thinking of displaying information in cards with Numbers wherever data is very less